# Gitignore falsely excludes a subfile

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a directory structure like this:

```
project
├── .gitignore
└── parent
    └── file.ts
```

Gitignore file content:

```
parent/*
!file.ts
```

Git does ignore everything under parent but `file.ts` which is weird because i did not exclude `file.ts` in parent dir in my `.gitignore` file.

What might be reason?

Comment: `git check-ignore --verbose parent/file.ts`

Comment: output `.gitignore:3:!file.ts   parent/file.ts`

Comment: From https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format: "It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded."

Comment: That's correct if I include `parent` in gitignore, however i use `parent/*`. Anyways, in my case, everything under parent directory is ignored. That part is ok but file.ts is not ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In gitignore, entries without a `/` mean all files in any directory.

This, `file.ts` matches all files named `file.ts` in any directories.

If you only want to exclude a `file.ts` on the top directory (where the `.gitignore` is) then use `./file.ts`.

Comment: It does not match 2 level deep sub folders. `parent/sub/file.ts` is ignored. But that's maybe because I also have `parent/*`.

Comment: @Mansur Doc says yes it matches. I think it might be some non-trivial side effect of the positive and negative rules in your .gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is related with the rule below. Copy pasted from https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format

> For example, a pattern doc/frotz/ matches doc/frotz directory, but not a/doc/frotz directory; however frotz/ matches frotz and a/frotz that is a directory (all paths are relative from the .gitignore file).